# pip install as source with dependencies separate

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to release a demo repository (where people can directly run python scripts to demonstrate some experiment).  I also need to include dependencies (numpy, etc).  I'd like to use pip to make it easy.

I've already made a setup.py file listing all the dependencies.  I'd now like to install my repo's code the the current directory, and all the dependencies to the default path (eg. `./venv/lib/python2.7`, `venv/src/`, etc).

Now, if I just run 
`pip install -e git+http://github.com/petered/my_repo.git#egg=my_repo`

Everything works, except the code in `my_repo` gets saved in the `/venv/src` (whereas I want it in the root directory).

I can also run 
`pip install -e git+http://github.com/petered/my_repo.git#egg=my_repo --target=.`

Which installs everything in the root (current) directory.  But then all dependencies also end up in this directory.

How can I pip install just the source code of a package in the current directory, but all dependencies in the default directory for dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My projects usually have a `setup.py` file that defines all dependencies. To install the project in a virtualenv I then first clone the repository and then simply [install the cloned repository](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs):

```
git clone http://github.com/petered/my_repo.git .
pip install -e .
```

This will install `my_repo` where it is, but install all dependencies into `lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

You will notice that this layout makes it possible to later publish the `my_repo` to PyPI, or install it as a dependency into `lib/...` if you wish to do so as the library itself has no idea about how it was installed.

Whenever I have several "private dependencies" (closed source, only available on our git server), I write installation instructions like

```
git clone http://github.com/petered/my_repo.git
git clone http://github.com/petered/my_repo_dependency_1.git
git clone http://github.com/petered/my_repo_dependency_2.git
pip install -e my_repo_dependency_1
pip install -e my_repo_dependency_2
pip install -e my_repo
```

in the readme file. This will install all private dependencies in place, but install all public PyPI dependencies in `lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

Comment: You are a saint.